# How do I loft lines into a mesh with Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

This is yet again my confusion with Meshing using Animation Nodes. My idea is to duplicate Lines into multiple Lines object, which later I could loft. Apparently this is not yet simple. Maybe possible, if possible how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you use an existing node to loft elements, which is the Spline Loft node instead. Basically, you create a bunch of splines before, feed that as a list to the node, and then decide on the amount of samples / divisions of the mesh. See this blend here:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the full setup:

[image: full setup]

The loop below is a workaround for me to get a few splines in the fashion that you did. I feed a list of integers into it, only using the loop index to generate a few start and end coordinates. With that, I create straight splines and collect them in a list at the end.

This spline list I feed back into the loft node. The samples parameter determines the number of points on the spline which the node generates. Spline Samples of 2 means, only start and end point, so a straight line. Important: you also need to set the samples in the other direction. That's why I get the list length in the end, so each spline is then sampled as a division as well.

Using a bit of randomness, you get this:

[image: random splines]